# Retrieving std::tuple object given its member value references

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, template-meta-programming, void-pointers, stdtuple

Let's say that I have an std::tuple:

```
std::tuple< int, float, bool > my_tuple;
```

and a function:

```
void my_function( int& i, float& f, bool& b);
```

Is it possible to retrieve the `my_tuple` object from within `my_function` if I can guarantee that its arguments `i, f, b` are members of `my_tuple`?

For example - is it legal to:

```
void my_function( int& i, float& f, bool& b){
  using tuple_type = std::tupl< int, float, bool >;
  tuple_type& my_tuple = *reinterpret_cast<tuple_type*>(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&i))
  // do stuff with my_tuple, like call its copy constructor, etc
}
```

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: I believe you could if you use a non-standard implementation of `tuple` that's guaranteed to be a [standard-layout type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_standard_layout) and guarantees which data member is first. You probably also need a `launder` in there even with those conditions fulfilled. This all begs for some standardese, though.